# google tag manager - data layer implementation for ecommerce

Tags: e-commerce, web-analytics, google-tag-manager, data-layers

I want to use Google Tag Manager for ecommerce tracking. I am just not sure in setting up of data layer. Is it me who implements that on the site or a programmer and I send him the data I need to get?

Thanks for your help and answers.

Answer (score 1):

Your programmer as per this documentation provided by Google : https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/3002596?hl=en